# Impossible to compare variable strings in nginx?

Tags: nginx, openresty

I have a simple comparison, I have checked that the strings are identical hmac hashes (base64 encoded), however this statement returns true from some reason. Why is Nginx not able to compare the strings correctly?

```
    if ($cookie_AUTHORIZATION != $signature ) { return 403; }
```

Comment: What's your config look like for setting `$signature`?  If you do something like `return 200 $signature` and `return 200 $cookie_AUTHORIZATION`, do you see any differences in output?